Where can we download the Spring Framework 2.5.6.SEC03 source code package?
I would like to find some "official" source code package for 2.5.6.SEC03 and build it locally.
But it seems that the the Spring Framework 2.x is EOL, and the gitHub repository(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework) only has versions after 3.x.
Where can we download the 2.5.6.SEC03 source code package?
Thanks.

I tried looking in Maven, but only found jars and sources.jar for version 2.5.6.SEC03, not source code. For example:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring/2.5.6.SEC03/

I try to find in sourceforge, but


(1)In "File" section of sourceforge, the latest version of the package containing the source code is only 2.5.5.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/springframework/files/springframework-2/2.5.5
"File" section of sourceforge
(2) In the "SVN" section of sourceforge, although the 2.5.6.SEC03 version is available, the content is actually jars and sources.jar, not the source code.
https://sourceforge.net/p/springframework/svn/15283/tree/repos/repo/org/springframework/spring/2.5.6.SEC03/
"SVN" section of sourceforge
(3) In addition, following the instructions in "CVS" section of sourceforge, the source code cannot be accessed and downloaded successfully.
https://sourceforge.net/p/springframework/cvs/

FIle spring-2.5.6.SEC03-sources.jar contains the sources, just unzip it, or import as a source archive into your IDE.

Thanks.  But I want to use the source code to build it locally.  Sources.jar does not seem to contain all the source code and cannot be used directly for compilation. It is seems different to "official" source code.

That version of Spring was build (in 2011) using Ant 1.7.1, and in the sources.jar there is no build.xml or depencies. But you can try to adapt the spring-2.5.6.SEC03.pom into a pom.xml to get all dependencies and import the sources to create your own project. Also check the correct jdk version, perhaps you have to use 1.6 or at most 1.7.
